# after I rollout my android app I get Draft status

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, rollout

Hello after I rollout my app yesterday and I got draft status and in review
and when I go to Dashboard it says Production active

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's active but is still `In review` you just have to wait once it will be available in PlayStore you will see something like [this](https://i.gyazo.com/b3572e142113a371e732f4e0116238ee.png)

Comment: Thank you my app get published after 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's active but is still In review you just have to wait once it will be available in PlayStore you will see something like [this](https://i.gyazo.com/b3572e142113a371e732f4e0116238ee.png)

Usually it takes from 24 to 48 hours but in some cases it can get up to 7 days for an app to be reviewed while if you publish a new release for a yet reviewed app it will take some hours.

[Here you can find more info](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859751?hl=en#zippy=%2Capp-status)